# T-SQL Efficient use of PARTITION BY and DISTINCT

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, distinct, partitioning

I have the following table to monitor user login to an application:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[userActivity](
    [userType] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [userInstanceID] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [userID] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [login] [datetime2](7) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

A particularity of my data is that a unique user is determined by the combination of `userType`, `userInstanceID`, and `userID`.

For instance, in the following image, I have three distinct users:

1. *customer 1 1* (red)
2. *employee 1 2* (blue)
3. *customer 2 1* (green)

[image]

My objective is to know:

1. The number of times each user has login
2. The most recent login
3. The oldest login

I have some test data as:

```
INSERT [dbo].[userActivity] ([userType], [userInstanceID], [userID], [login]) VALUES (N'customer  ', N'1         ', N'1         ', CAST(N'2020-09-17T18:00:07.2492412' AS DateTime2))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[userActivity] ([userType], [userInstanceID], [userID], [login]) VALUES (N'employee  ', N'1         ', N'2         ', CAST(N'2020-09-18T09:00:07.2494560' AS DateTime2))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[userActivity] ([userType], [userInstanceID], [userID], [login]) VALUES (N'customer  ', N'1         ', N'1         ', CAST(N'2020-08-17T03:00:07.2492412' AS DateTime2))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[userActivity] ([userType], [userInstanceID], [userID], [login]) VALUES (N'customer  ', N'2         ', N'1         ', CAST(N'2020-07-23T10:00:07.2492412' AS DateTime2))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[userActivity] ([userType], [userInstanceID], [userID], [login]) VALUES (N'customer  ', N'2         ', N'1         ', CAST(N'2020-10-25T11:00:07.2492412' AS DateTime2))
GO
```

I was able to get what I need with the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userType, userInstanceID, userID, numberOfLogins, MostRecentLogin, oldestLogin FROM (
    SELECT userType, userInstanceID, userID, 
        COUNT(login) OVER(PARTITION BY userType, userInstanceID, userID ORDER BY userType, userInstanceID, userID) AS numberOfLogins,
        max(login) OVER(PARTITION BY userType, userInstanceID, userID ORDER BY userType, userInstanceID, userID) AS MostRecentLogin,
        min(login) OVER(PARTITION BY userType, userInstanceID, userID ORDER BY userType, userInstanceID, userID) AS oldestLogin
        FROM dbo.userActivity) AS summary
```

[image]

My question is:  **is this and efficient method?**  I have millions of rows and around 20 columns to bring along for each user.

I appreciate any suggestion.

Thanks!

Comment: *" is this and efficient method?"* No, use non-windowed aggregates and a `GROUP BY` not a `DISTINCT` and windowed functions.

Comment: Hi @Larnu, thanks for the reply!  Could you please be a bit more specific on the "windowed functions"?

Comment: It looks like a textbook example for introducing `GROUP BY`, not `PARTITION`.

Comment: What you have above are windowed functions, @Wilmar, due to the use of the `OVER` clause. [SELECT - OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) You *don't want* windowed functions, just "normal" aggregation. [COUNT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Hi @Damien_The_Unbeliever, thanks for the reply.  So, something like this:
```SELECT userType, userInstanceID, userID, count(login) as numberLogin, MAX(login) as MostRecentLogin, MIN(Login) as oldestLogin
 FROM dbo.userActivity GROUP BY userType, userInstanceID, userID``` ?

Comment: Thanks @Larnu! Since my objective is to understand the performance implications.  What is wrong with windowed functions?  I am asking in a "I want to learn" way rather than a contestary way.

Comment: The window functions are the "bad" part, it's really the `DISTINCT`. `DISTINCT` is a very expensive operator unless the specific indexes the instance needs are there; and then it can rely on them to get the `DISTINCT` values.

Comment: I get it @Larnu.  Thanks very much for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first "smell" with what you wrote is that your `PARTITION BY` columns in each case are a) the same and b) the only non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT` list<sup>1</sup>.

The second "smell" is `DISTINCT`. No, really. It's far too often used when someone says "Well, I'm getting the results I need, except I'm getting multiple rows when I only wanted one". The bad approach is to apply `DISTINCT` and to not think about why you were getting those multiple results.

In your case you're getting multiple results because you're not aggregating correctly.

Looking back at your problem, you're saying "for each unique combination of *these columns* I want to computed *these aggregates*". Which is pretty well the definition of `GROUP BY`<sup>2</sup>. So yes, the straightforward way of writing this query is:

```
select userType, userInstanceID, userID,
       COUNT(*) as numLogins, MIN(login) as firstLogin, MAX(login) as lastLogin
from dbo.userActivity
group by userType, userInstanceID, userID
```

You'll notice this is shorter and uses fewer features, which is usually a way to tell you've got the query into *a* form most likely to be well optimized by the optimizer.

---

<sup>1</sup>Taken together, these mean that you're going to *potentially* compute exactly the same result rows multiple times. Whether you actually do depends on a) whether you have multiple rows with the same unique combinations and b) how smart the optimizer is being.

<sup>2</sup>I'd suggest strongly that any time you're contemplating `DISTINCT` you ought to be thinking `GROUP BY`. `DISTINCT` is effectively `GROUP BY *`<sup>3</sup>, but it's rare to not have aggregates when grouping.

<sup>3</sup>Except the `*` being "all columns in the `SELECT` clause" rather than "all columns produced by the `FROM`/`JOIN`s".

Comment: Thank you @Damin_The_Unbeliever, for the detailed explanation.  With `GROUP BY` I always get confused when I have fields that I do not want to group under and fields that I do not want to group under.  For instance, let's say I have fields: `a, b, c, d`. in a table.  And I want to bring all values but only gouped by `a, b`.  For instance:  ```SELECT a,b,,c,d, COUNT(c) FROM myTable GROUP BY a, b;```  I get an error saying that `c, d` also have to be in the `GROUP BY`.  That is why I ended up trying with PARTITION BY which was more clear.